# What happens to cybertron after the events of the Dark of the Moon?

Tags: transformers

I like watching transformers, it's exciting to watch it every time. I was watching the 3rd part: [Dark of the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Dark_of_the_Moon)  yesterday with my friends.

After finishing the movie I thought: *what happened to the Planet Cybertron after the events of the dark of the moon. was it completely destroyed or something else happened?*

Are there any relevance to this incident in comic? Also are there any such incidents mentioned where Decepticons were able to revive the Cybertron back?

Comment: I haven’t downvoted, although I feel I should just for this: “it's exciting to watch it every time”. It wasn’t even exciting to watch the first time!

Comment: “its not a valid reason to downvote” Isn’t it? It’s only downvoting. They’re only internet points.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I know you said you didn't downvote, but the hover over text on the downvote button indicates that downvotes are meant to be for questions that do not show research effort or questions that are unclear or not useful. Although that isn't a rule per se, I would argue that downvoting a question because you don't like the thing the question is asking about would be a misuse of votes. Additionally, a low rep user is going to feel those downvotes more than a high rep user like yourself would.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: yeah, true true. (Just to split hairs — and this doesn’t contradict your assessment of downvoting, which I think is entirely valid — I wasn’t exactly suggesting I’d downvote because I didn’t like the thing being asked about. I suggested I’d downvote because of what I consider to be over-effusive praise of the thing being asked about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Movieverse:**
From the looks inside the film (as far as I'm aware the only resource currently) cybertron collapsed onto itself when the gate was shut down, thus resulting in its utter destruction.

**Other parts:**
So far I never have seen any source (comic, cartoons,...) where cybertron was completely destroyed....lifeless yes but never destroyed aside from the dark moon.

That aside to answer your last question: Yes Cybertron has been revived a few times but ONLY by the Autobots. Best example here is the cartoon series (G2).